# Update HTML from JSP file

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I got a problem where I am not sure how to implement the desired behaviour.

I want to show the contents of a svn repository in a TreeView. So I have a Java Class which connects to the repository and stores the repositories contents in my Java DataModel. Then in my .jsp file I create a TreeView with HTML and Javascript and update the contents of the TreeView accordingly. The problem is, that I need to listen for an event when another node is selected, since I want to show the according revision number on the site too. The event is of course implemented in Javascript, because the TreeView is too. So I need to call my Java Class with the selected node from the Javascript Event and show the results in the html(.jsp) file.

How would i do this ? I do not know how to implement the correct behaviour here. Is this even possible ?

So to sum up my task:

- Get repository file/folder names from java library
- Show information in TreeView
- If another node in TreeView was selected, get selected files revision number from java library
- Show information on site

Maybe you can enlighten me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you what to implement an ajax call within your javascript code.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
         document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out tommorow and come back to you. Basically in my event listener for selection I make an Ajax request to a jsp file where i return the revision number from my Java DataModel and set the response on my html page, right ?

Comment: Correct. You could return a value, some json (javascript object notation) or html and then use javascript to display the information or process it further.